# What version of JDK should I use?

Tags: java, gradle, jvm

today I wanted to update my version of Gradle 7.4.1 to the latest version i.e. 8.3, everything is going well except that:

When I go to open the project with InteliJ I get this error: "JDK 20.0.2 isn't compatible with Gradle 8.3. Please fix JAVA_HOME environment variable." then the question arises: "which version should I use?"

I try to do a search on the internet I can't find anything and indeed a table from the official gradle site tells me that the JDK I use 20.0.2 is correct and works

at this point I decided to ask you... what can you tell me?

Comment: [Gradle says 8.3 is compatible with Java 20](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html), so this is likely a bug in IntelliJ  or the IDE is simply working on outdated information (Gradle 8.3 was released only 4 days ago).

Comment: absurdly it shows me this error also in versions 8.0 and 8.1 at this point I try to see if InteliJ works with data otherwise I stay at 7.4.1

Thanks for the replies;

Comment: If Gradle and IntelliJ disagree about which versions of Java that Gradle is compatible with, you should believe Gradle. You can try ignoring the "error" emitted by IntelliJ. Or maybe try invalidating caches, deleting the `.gradle` folder, etc..

Comment: Be sure you have the latest version of IntelliJ. Releases happen multiple times per year. Indeed, rather than manually installing IntelliJ, install their [*JetBrains Toolbox*](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/). That tool installs IntelliJ, reminds you when updates are available, and handles updating IntelliJ for you.

Comment: Also, as Slaw said, IntelliJ occasionally gets confused. Doing a  [“invalidate caches”](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/invalidate-caches.html) and a restart usually fixes things. Maven and Gradle also get confused on occasion. Delete the hidden `.m2` and `.gradle` folders respectively to clear their caches. Wait patiently on next use as their caches repopulate.